# Homotopy limits of weak diagrams

Tags: ct.category-theory, homotopy-theory, higher-category-theory, model-categories

This question is somehow related to my question at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/683915/derived-pseudo-functor
and to the question here: [A homotopy commutative diagram that cannot be strictified](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/81721/a-homotopy-commutative-diagram-that-cannot-be-strictified) .

Consider a model category $M$. Let us assume that, for all small category $S$,
we can endow the category $Fun (S, M) $ with the injective model structure.

So, considering a given small category $S$, we got the notion of a homotopy limit $ Ho(Fun (S, M))\to Ho(M) $.

My first question is: which would be the correct notion of homotopy limit $ Fun (S, Ho(M))\to Ho(M) $? The second question is: how can I study the existence of such a homotopy limit?

I know that if the diagonal functor $ \Delta : Ho (M)\to Fun (S, Ho(M)) $ has a right adjoint, then the answer is clear. But, also, I do know that this situation is rare for model categories $ M $ (considering $S$ being not discrete).
However, in the general situation, I guess that the correct notion of a such homotopy limit is the following:

Consider the projections $\lambda : M\to Ho(M) $ and $ \alpha : Fun(S, M)\to Ho (Fun (S, M)) $. The functor $ Fun ( S, \lambda ) $ has a total derived functor
$ i: Ho ( Fun (S, M) ) \to Fun (S , Ho (M) ) $. I would define the homotopy limit $ Fun ( S, Ho(M)) $  as being a right Kan extension of the usual homotopy limit $ Ho(Fun (S, M))\to Ho (M) $ along thar derived functor $ i $.

I guess that, one example of such a homotopy limit is the 2 (weak) - limit (homotopy limit) of a pseudo functor $ A: S\to Cat $.

But, if this is the correct notion of such a homotopy limit, my question remains: how can I study the existence of that right Kan extension? Where can I find about this kind of homotopy limit?

Thank you in advance

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by homotopy limit $Fun(S,Ho(M))\to Ho(M))$. Do you mean a right adjoint of the diagonal functor ? Then this is just a limit. The homotopy category of any cofibrantly generated model category is weakly complete and weakly cocomplete, i.e. limits and colimits exist but are not unique. This is explained in M. Hovey's book _Model Categories_.

Comment: @PhilippeGaucher I don't mean the right adjoint of the diagonal functor. I'm trying to deal with the case in which the right adjoint to the diagonal functor doesn't exist. And, in this case, I would define the homotopy limit as the Kan extension I defined above.
In almost all the cases I know, $Ho (M) $ is not complete or cocomplete.

Comment: @PhilippeGaucher As I said, I'm not aware of any case in which the homotopy category is complete: but I know that, in this case, the right notion would be the limit itself. 
I will search for that result you said (about weakly completeness), since I don't know what do you mean by "the limits exist but they are not unique". (Aren't you talking about the (usual) homotopy limits?).
Thank you for your comment.

Comment: A category is weakly (co)complete if (co)limits exist but are not unique. The homotopy category of a model category is weakly complete and weakly cocomplete. (I cannot understand why @Fernando does not appear when I write it at the beginning of the comment ; could someone help me to edit this comment ?)

Comment: Answering 1), there is no such a correct notion.

Comment: @FernandoMuro I think that a good notion Of such a homotopy limit would generalize the case of weak limits of pseudofunctors. I mean weak 2-limit of a pseudofunctor. And, for a weak diagram D that could be strictified, this good notion would be such that: the homotopy limit of D is the homotopy limit of the strictified one. So I guess I was looking for the right Kan extension... But my question remains: is there a tool or theory to deal easily with the problem of the existence of such a Kan extension? Or this is a trivial problem?

Comment: I mean, it would be a great surprise for me (I dare say for many) if such a good notion existed at all. I don't think it's tivial but unfeasible, but I may be wrong!

Comment: @FernandoMuro Actually, I do know that the existence of such a Kan extension would be not expected in general. When I asked if the question would be trivial, I was asking if the solution woulb be something uninteresting as: "the right Kan extension exists if and only if the model category is somehow trivial".
For example, "the right Kan extension exists if and only if all diagrams could be strictified" or if the model category is trivial... something like this.

Comment: I don't think it's trivial in that sense, but honestly I don't know.