# An H-group that's not a loop space?

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

Recall that an [H-group](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/H-space) is a space $X$ (in the sense of homotopy theory, so say CW complex) that is a group object in the homotopy category.  I.e., there's a multiplication map $X \times X \rightarrow X$ which is associative up to homotopy and with an inverse map again up to homotopy.  The standard example of an H-group is a loop space $\Omega X$.  What is a simple example of an H-group that is not a loop space?

If I understand the language right, I'm asking for a group-like $A_3$ algebra that's not $A_\infty$.  If I were asking for $A_2$ but not $A_3$ then I know $S^7$ is a good example.

My motivation is illustrating some of the subtleties in defining $\infty$-groups for a HoTT seminar.

Comment: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/81721/a-homotopy-commutative-diagram-that-cannot-be-strictified

Have a look at Dylan Wilson's answer.

Comment: @DavidC:  I even ran across that question when googling, but failed to scroll down to the last answer.  Thanks!

Comment: That said, that answer is a bit advanced and terse for me, I'd love to see it fleshed out in one of the simplest cases. Does $RP^2$ satisfy the assumptions of that answer?

Comment: For example, it seems plausible that $RP^2$ is an H-subgroup of $SO(3)$, but the lack of higher cells means it's no longer coherently associative.

Comment: Dylan's answer quotes Stasheff; Stasheff's paper http://www.jstor.org/stable/1993608 includes the examples $M(Q(p),2n+1)$ where $Q(p)$ is the $p$-adic subgroup of the rationals --- this is $A_{p-1}$ but not $A_p$.

Comment: $RP^2$ cannot be an $H$-space; **Exercises** there are four homotopy classes of map $RP^2\to RP^2$, and there are four homotopy classes of map $\Sigma RP^2 \to \Sigma RP^2$; but the suspension $RP^2\to \Omega\Sigma RP^2$ misses the degree-2 map.  (otherwise the cofiber of something would have a nontrivial $Sq^2$ acting on $H^1$! ) Consequently, some of the four maps below get confused in the suspension, too. Upshot is that no map $\Omega\Sigma RP^2 \to RP^2 $ can be a retraction.

Comment: @JesseC.McKeown:  Thanks!  I think I misunderstood what the word "divisible" meant in the context of Dylan's answer (which is why I thought Y(Z/2Z,1) satisfied the assumptions).  It's a bit of a shame that these examples are so complicated.  I don't think this would work as an example that CS graduate students could understand.

Comment: I haven't checked that smaller examples, like $M(Z/p, 2n+1)$ don't work; but I'm guessing what Stashef's calculations would show is that $\Sigma^{2n} RP^2$ is $A_1$ but not $A_2$.  And $A_1$ isn't a whole lot.

Answer (score 11):

The first example appears in the paper "Homotopy associativity and finite
CW complexes" Topology vol.9 (1970) 121-128 by Alexander Zabrodsky. With
present knowledge it is possible to construct many examples.
Here are some examples.  Consider Sp(n) with n 3 or more, or G_2.  Construct X from a pullback diagram of p-local spaces, where X localized at 2 or 3 is the Lie group and localized at the remaining primes is the product of local sphere having the same type as the Lie group. Then X is homotopy associative because each of its localizations is homotopy associative. The space X is not a mod p group for p between 5 and 2n  if Sp(n) is used and not a mod 5 group if G_2 is used in the construction. The latter claim is based of a theorem proved by Clarence Wilkerson, "K-theory Operations in mod-p Loop Spaces"  Math.Z. 132, 29-44, (1973)

Comment: Welcome to mathoverflow John!